# javascript timer based on world clock?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

hey guys,
is it possible to fire a function (every second or every 500ms) based on a global world clock or something? I need a simultaneous time on each computer that opens this script!

any idea how to solve this?

regards

Comment: I would only say to synchronise the client computer to a world clock to the millisecond every minute/hour. And rely on that. Otherwise you will have to make your own timer network.

Comment: Are you going to use it or show it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the world time with some server implementation.

Then you could either decrement it with some `setTimeout` function with a `time--` on the time,
or you could decrement it with some `ajax` call back to the server which would get the exact time again (also with a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` timer)